# Hello world typescript code gets syntaxError: Unexpected token ':' when debugging

Tags: typescript

I created a minimum typescript project containing very simple code.

Project structure:

```
my-ts/
     - hello.ts
     - tsconfig.json
```

hello.ts

```
let message: string = "Hello world";
console.log(message);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "out"
    }
}
```

On VS Code IDE, when I press F5 which starts running the code with debugger,  the debugger console shows error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError /Users/john/Projects/my-ts/hello.ts:1
let message: string = "Hello world";
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Why is this error? Could someone please explain the root cause?

Answer (score 3):

Node.js can't run TypeScript natively, but you're passing it TypeScript code.

You'll need *some* kind of build step where TypeScript (or similar) compiles the TypeScript to JavaScript and you then run that JavaScript in Node.js. One popular way to do this is [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node):

1. Install it via `npm install --save-dev ts-node`
2. In `.vscode/launch.json`, add this to the `configurations` array:

   ```json
   {
       "type": "node",
       "request": "launch",
       "name": "Launch Program",
       "runtimeArgs": [
           "-r",
           "ts-node/register"
       ],
       "args": [
           "${workspaceFolder}/hello.ts"
       ]
   }
   ```

Now, pressing F5 in a `.ts` file will tell `ts-node` to compile the code to JavaScript and run the result.

Alternatively, you could use [Deno](https://deno.land/) (from the creators of Node.js), which runs TypeScript natively.

Answer (score 1):

@T.J.Crowder's answer is right.

But for my simple project I don't need `package.json` as my project directory structure indicated in my post. Only one `.ts` file & one `tsconfig.json`.

So, I solved it another way, that's in `tsconfig.json` add `"sourceMap":true`, then F5 would just run the code correctly.